# how to get last cell in sapui column

Tags: javascript, sapui5

```
var table = this.getView().byId("myTableData");
var column = table.getColumns()[0];
```

So I have first column selected here, but how do we get last cell in this column?

I've tried playing with table.getRows() and mapping the index, but the problem is, my columns are not always visible, so that's not a good solution.

Anyway, it feels here it should be something more elegant..

```
      <t:Table id="myTableData"
        rows="{SomeData>/RowData}"
        alternateRowColors="true"
        rowSelectionChange="handleNewItemScaleSelectionChange">
        <t:columns>
          <t:Column width="100%" resizable="false" flexible="false" hAlign="Left" visible="{someModel>/visibility}">
           <m:Text text="{someModel>Text}"/>
           <t:template>
            <m:Text text="{SomeModel>ThisData}" FontWeightBold" hAlign="Right" />
           </t:template>
          </t:Column>
          <t:Column width="100%" resizable="false" flexible="false" hAlign="Right">
           <m:Text text="hello"/>
           <t:template>
             <m:Text  text="Hello"/>
           </t:template>
          </t:Column>
        </t:columns>
      </t:Table>
```

Comment: If `table.getColumns()` returns a complete array of all hidden and visible columns , getting that array's length helps you to reach last item/column.

Comment: maybe you should take a step back to understand why do you need to get the last cell? In a MVC paradigm, you should not need to do so. Thanks

Comment: Please provide some context. Telling us what you want to achieve could help us solving the actual problem. What do you want to do witht the last cell?

Comment: I need to add tooltip, to the last cell of a certain column.

Comment: Is it a XML or JS Table? You can add the tooltip in your columns template. Can you post your table?

Comment: its XML table, with rows property. So row count is not know. Also some columns are hidden sometimes. Column.GetCells() would be perfect here, but.. :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `.length` to get the last index of the rows or Columns